# Async promises recursion with unknow supply of async values

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recursion, promise

I'm banging my head around async promises recursion. I have bunch of promises that resolve when async data is download (combined by Promise.all). But sometimes in the data that I just download there is link to another data, that must be download (recursion). The best explanation is showing code I guess. Comments are in code.
(I have tried various combinations to no avail.)

```
var urls = ['http://czyprzy.vdl.pl/file1.txt', 'http://czyprzy.vdl.pl/file2.txt', 'http://czyprzy.vdl.pl/file3.txt'];
var urlsPromise = [];
var secondPart = [];
var thirdPart = [];

function urlContent(url, number) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    var dl = request(url, function (err, resp, content) {
      if (err || resp.statusCode >= 400) {
        return resolve({number : number, url : url, error : 'err'});
      }
      if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
        if (content.indexOf('file') !== -1) // if there is 'file' inside content we need (would like to :) download this new file by recursion
        {
            content = content.slice(content.indexOf('file') + 4);
            content =+ content; // (number to pass later on, so we know what file we are working on)
            url = 'http://czyprzy.vdl.pl/file' + content + '.txt'; // (we build new address)

            //urlsPromise.push(urlContent(url, content)); // this will perform AFTER Promise.all(urlsPromise) so we simply can't do recurention (like that) here
            secondPart.push(urlContent(url, content)); // if we use another promise array that put resolved items to that array everything will work just fine - but only till first time, then we would need to add another (thirdPart) array and use another Promise.all(thirdPart)... and so on and so on... --- the problem is I don't know how many files there will be, so it means I have no idea how many 'parts' for Promise.all I need to create, some kind of asynchronous loop/recursion would save me here, but I don't know how to do that properly so the code can run in proper order
        }
        return resolve({number : number, url : url}); // this goes to 'urlsPromise' array
      }
    });
  });
}

if (urls.length !== 0) {
  for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++)
  {urlsPromise.push(urlContent(urls[i], i + 1));}
}

Promise.all(urlsPromise).then(function(urlsPromise) {
  console.log('=======================================');
  console.log('urlsPromise:\n');
  console.log(urlsPromise); // some code/calculations here
}).then(function() {
  return Promise.all(secondPart).then(function(secondPart) {
    console.log('=======================================');
    console.log('secondPart:\n');
    console.log(secondPart); // some code/calculations here
    secondPart.forEach(function(item)
    {
        thirdPart.push(urlContent(item.url, item.number + 3));
    });
  });
}).then(function() {
  return Promise.all(thirdPart).then(function(thirdPart) {
    console.log('=======================================');
    console.log('thirdPart:\n');
    console.log(thirdPart); // some code/calculations here
  });
}).then(function()
{
    console.log();
    console.log('and so on and so on...');
});



//// files LINKING (those files do exist on live server - just for testing purposes):
// file1->file4->file7->file10  /-/ file1 content: file4 /-/ file4 content: file7 /-/ file7 content: file10
// file2->file5->file8->file11  /-/ file2 content: file5 /-/ file5 content: file8 /-/ file8 content: file11
// file3->file6->file9->file12  /-/ file3 content: file6 /-/ file6 content: file9 /-/ file9 content: file12



//// the console.log output looks like this:
// =======================================
// urlsPromise:

// [ { number: 1, url: 'http://czyprzy.vdl.pl/file4.txt' },
//   { number: 2, url: 'http://czyprzy.vdl.pl/file5.txt' },
//   { number: 3, url: 'http://czyprzy.vdl.pl/file6.txt' } ]
// =======================================
// secondPart:

// [ { number: 4, url: 'http://czyprzy.vdl.pl/file7.txt' },
//   { number: 5, url: 'http://czyprzy.vdl.pl/file8.txt' },
//   { number: 6, url: 'http://czyprzy.vdl.pl/file9.txt' } ]
// =======================================
// thirdPart:

// [ { number: 7, url: 'http://czyprzy.vdl.pl/file10.txt' },
//   { number: 8, url: 'http://czyprzy.vdl.pl/file11.txt' },
//   { number: 9, url: 'http://czyprzy.vdl.pl/file12.txt' } ]

// and so on and so on...
```

Comment: [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) keywords might help, if you're able to use it. It makes working with promises much easier and more readable.

Comment: I thinkI can't in this particular case. But an example (preferable on this question code sample) that use async/await would help me to write similar code with use of promises (I guess, cause async is just synthetic sugar for promises).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was provided thanks to **trincot** - https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459839/trincot

When I asked him this question directly, he support me with time and knowledge and give this excellent answer.

CODE:

```
//// files LINKING (those files do exist on live server - just for testing purposes):
// file1->file4(AND file101)->file7->file10  /-/ file1 content: file4 /-/ file4 content: file7 /-/ file7 content: file10 /-/ file10 content: EMPTY /-/ file101 content: EMPTY
// file2->file5(AND file102)->file8->file11  /-/ file2 content: file5 /-/ file5 content: file8 /-/ file8 content: file11 /-/ file11 content: EMPTY /-/ file102 content: EMPTY
// file3->file6(AND file103)->file9->file12  /-/ file3 content: file6 /-/ file6 content: file9 /-/ file9 content: file12 /-/ file12 content: EMPTY /-/ file103 content: EMPTY

var urls = ['http://czyprzy.vdl.pl/file1.txt', 'http://czyprzy.vdl.pl/file2.txt', 'http://czyprzy.vdl.pl/file3.txt'];
var urlsPromise = [];

function requestPromise(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request(url, function (err, resp, content) {
            if (err || resp.statusCode != 200) reject(err || resp.statusCode);
            else resolve(content);
        });
    });
}

async function urlContent(url, number) {
  var arr = [];
  let content = await requestPromise(url);

  while (content.indexOf(';') !== -1)
  {
    var semiColon = content.indexOf(';');
var fileLink = content.slice(content.indexOf('file'), semiColon + 1);
content = content.replace(fileLink, ''); // we need to remove the file link so we won't iterate over it again, we will add to the array only new links
var fileLinkNumber = fileLink.replace('file', '');
fileLinkNumber = fileLinkNumber.replace(';', '');
fileLinkNumber =+ fileLinkNumber;
url = 'http://czyprzy.vdl.pl/file' + fileLinkNumber + '.txt'; // we build new address
arr.push({url, fileLinkNumber});
}
if (content.indexOf('file') !== -1)
{
var fileLinkNumber = content.slice(content.indexOf('file') + 4);
fileLinkNumber =+ fileLinkNumber;
  url = 'http://czyprzy.vdl.pl/file' + fileLinkNumber + '.txt';
  arr.push({url, fileLinkNumber});
}
var newArr = arr.map(function(item)
{
return urlContent(item.url, item.fileLinkNumber); // return IS important here
});
return [].concat(arr, ...await Promise.all(newArr));
}

async function doing() {
    let urlsPromise = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        urlsPromise.push(urlContent(urls[i], i + 1));
    }
    let results = [].concat(...await Promise.all(urlsPromise)); // flatten the array of arrays
    console.log(results);
}

//// this is only to show Promise.all chaining - so you can do async loop, and then wait for some another async data - in proper chain.

var test_a = ['http://czyprzy.vdl.pl/css/1.css', 'http://czyprzy.vdl.pl/css/2.css', 'http://czyprzy.vdl.pl/css/cssa/1a.css', 'http://czyprzy.vdl.pl/css/cssa/2a.css'];
var promisesTest_a = [];

function requestStyle(url)
{
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
{
request(url, function(error, response, content)
{
if (response.statusCode === 200 && !error)
{resolve(content);}
else
{reject(error);}
});
});
}

for (var i = 0; i < test_a.length; i++)
{promisesTest_a.push(requestStyle(test_a[i]));}

Promise.all(promisesTest_a).then(function(promisesTest_a)
{
   console.log(promisesTest_a);
}).then(function()
{
   console.log('\nNow we start with @imports...\n');
}).then(function()
{
   return doing();
}).then(function()
{
   console.log('ALL DONE!');
});
```

COMMENT:

At first the explanation what is [...] - destructured rest parameters (just in case if you don't know it).

```
var arr = [];
var array1 = ['one', 'two', 'three']
var array2 = [['four', 'five', ['six', 'seven']], 'eight', 'nine', 'ten'];
arr = array1.concat(array2);
console.log(arr); // it does not flattern the array - it just concatenate them (join them together)
console.log('---');
// however
arr = array1.concat(...array2);
console.log(arr); // notice the [...] - as you can see it flatern the array - 'four' and 'five' are pull out of an array - think of it as level up :) remember that it pull up WHOLE array that is deeper - so 'six' and 'seven' are now 1 level deep (up from 2 levels deep, but still in another array).
console.log('---');
// so
arr = [].concat(...arr);
console.log(arr); // hurrrray our array is flat (single array without nested elements)
console.log();
```

All files (links) that are ready to be download (those 3 starting ones in a **urls** array) are downloaded almost immediately (synchronous loop over array that contain them - one after the other, but very fast, right away cause we simply iterate over them in synchronous way).

Then, when we have their contents (cause we Await till content is downloaded - so we got a resolved promise data here) we start to look for info about other possible urls (files) related to the one we already got, to download them (via async recursion).

When we found all the info about possible additional urls/files (presented in an array of regexs - **matches**), we push it to data array (named **arr** in our code) and download them (thanks to the mutation of url).

We download them by return the *async* **urlContent** function that need to *Await* for **requestPromise** promise (so we have the resolve/rejected data in **urlContent** so if needed we can mutate it - build proper url to get the next file/content).

And so on, so on, till we "iterate" (download) over all files. Every time the urlContent is called, it return an array of promises (**promises variable**) that initially are pending. When we await Promise.all(promises) the execution only resumes at that spot when ALL those promises have been resolved. And so, at that moment, we have the values for each of these promises. Each of these is an array. We use one big concat to nit all those arrays together into one big array, also including the elements of **arr** (we need to remmeber that it can be more then 1 file to download from file we have already download - that is why we store values in data array - named **arr** in code - which store **promiseReques** function resolved/rejected values). This "big" array is the value, with which a promise is resolved. Recall that this promise is the one that was returned already by this current function context, at the time the first await was executed.

This is important part - so it (urlContent) returns (await) a single promise and that (returned) promise is resolved with an array as value. Note that an async function returns the promise to the caller immediately, when the first await is encountered. The return statement in an async function determines what the value is with which that returned promise is resolved. In our case that is an array.

So urlContent at every call return an promise - resolved value in a array - [...] (destructured rest parameters - returns a promise that eventually resolves to an array), that is collected by our async **doing**  function (cause 3 urls was fired at start - every one has it own urlContent function... path), that collect (Await!) all those arrays from Promise.all(urlsPromise), and when they are resolved (we await for them to be resolved and passed by Promise.all) it 'return' your data (results variable). To be precise, doing returns a promise (because it is async). But the way that we call doing, we show we are not interested in what this promise resolves to, and in fact, since **doing** does not have a return statement, that promise resolves to UNDEFINED (!). Anyway, we don't use it - we merely output the results to the console.

One thing that can be confusing with async functions is that the return statement is *not* executed when the function returns (what is in a name, right!? ;). The function has already returned when it executed the first await. When eventually it executes the return statement, it does not really return a value, but it resolves "its own" promise; the one it had returned earlier. If we would really want to separate output from logic, we should not do console.log(results) there, but do return results, and then, where we call doing, we could do doing.then(console.log); Now we do use the promise returned by doing!

I would reserve the verb "*to return*" for what the *caller* of a function gets back from it *synchronously*.
I would use "*to resolve*" for the action that sets a promise to a *resolved state with a value*, a value that can be accessed with *await* or *.then()*.

Answer (score 0):

The await keyword can massively simplify this. You won't need to use a self recursive function. This demo fakes the server call with a randomly sized array.

https://jsfiddle.net/mvwahq19/1/

```js
// setup: create a list witha  random number of options.
var sourceList = [];
var numItems = 10 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);

for (var i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
{
    sourceList.push(i);
}

sourceList.push(100);

var currentIndex = 0;

// a function which returns a promise. Imagine it is asking a server.
function getNextItem() {
    var item = sourceList[currentIndex];
    currentIndex++;
    
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          resolve(item);
        }, 100);
    });
}

async function poll() {
    var collection = [];
    var done = false;
    while(!done) {
        var item = await getNextItem();
        
        collection.push(item);
        
        console.log("Got another item", item);
        
        if (item >= 100) {
            done = true;
        }
    }
    console.log("Got all items", collection);
}

poll();
```

You can write a normal for loop except the contents use await.